# Yellow screen (YSOD) and unhelpful errors when trying to edit the renderings/presentation details on a page

Tags: presentation

I have a 8.0 site that just started having some problems whenever I try to edit the Renderings (both final and shared). I'm getting a yellow screen displaying as soon as I hit "Edit", as seen here:
[image]

Upon checking the logs, I can't decipher anything too helpful:

> 7064 14:18:30 ERROR Application error.
>   Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
>   Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
>   Source: System.Web
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>      at ASP.sitecore_shell_default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> Nested Exception
>   Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   Source: mscorlib
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
>      at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CallMethod(Type type, Object obj, String methodName, Boolean includeNonPublic, Boolean includeInherited, Boolean includeStatic, Object[] parameters)
>      at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Web.UI.SecurePage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> Nested Exception
>   Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
>   Message: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: value
>   Source: Sitecore.Kernel
>      at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
>      at Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.SafeEncode(String value)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Layouts.DeviceEditor.DeviceEditorForm.RenderRenderings(DeviceDefinition deviceDefinition, Int32 selectedIndex, Int32 index)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Layouts.DeviceEditor.DeviceEditorForm.Refresh()
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Layouts.DeviceEditor.DeviceEditorForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)

This template has standard values for renderings that we aren't overriding, and I'm able to edit the renderings on the standard values just fine.

In case its helpful, here's the raw values of the Shared and Final renderings fields (sorry for the image, but the Stack Exchange editor didn't like the markup):
[image]

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you overriden the Layout Details Modal? It is causing the above error because it cannot pass the Placeholder. Try remove the placeholder from the Standard Values in the final layout and then click on the edit from the item

Comment: Hey @HishaamNamooya, no, nothing in the modal is overridden

Comment: Please see answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have been able to replicate the error you are having. The reason is because the placeholder are left blank.

For example, I have this xml for the Shared Layout:

```
<r xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ><d id="{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}" l="{14030E9F-CE92-49C6-AD87-7D49B50E42EA}"><r id="{CE4ADCFB-7990-4980-83FB-A00C1E3673DB}" ph="test" uid="{52BDC987-3ED2-42DF-B69F-57B5B8C1EE1C}" /></d></r>
```

If I remove the `ph="test"`, it will crash with the error you mentioned.

From the screenshot you provided as shown below, there are no placeholders in the entries. You will require to either update the `XML` manually by adding:

**For Shared Layout**

```
ph=""
```

Example:

```
<r id="{CE4ADCFB-7990-4980-83FB-A00C1E3673DB}" ph="" uid="{52BDC987-3ED2-42DF-B69F-57B5B8C1EE1C}" />
```

**For Final Layout**

```
s:ph""
```

Example:

```
<r uid="{F991D823-656C-44A2-B89C-B4AAFD172A5F}" s:ph="" />
```

This will at least help you to open the modal without errors. Note that, once you are able to open the modal, you need to set the appropriate placeholder value.

Or you can do it from the Standard Values. But I am pretty sure you will need to do it manually, that is, modifying the xml.

[image]

In your screenshot you provided, you already see that there is only 1 rendering that has a placeholder. The first one in the Final Layout, which is **SecondarySidebar**.

Comment: Thank you for your help. On the standard values presentation details raw values, I added s:ph"" to each of the final renderings, and that allowed me to go into the modal. There, I saw a bunch of renderings that shouldn't have been there - so I deleted them, and made sure everything had a placeholder. Now the pages themselves were fixed too.

Comment: In my experience, locate the offending rendering / layout, click and open, add a placeholder value, and then click the "edit" button. Works.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this as well (7.2) and since I didn't want to mess with the XML, I first went into all of the controls to verify they had a placeholder set, and if they did not, put in and then erased a space.

After pressing OK and saving the item I was able to go back into Presentation Details and Edit.

On a second item that this was happening I went into the control I thought was causing the issue (it has a default placeholder and the datasource points to an item now set to never publish) then pressed OK with no changes. I was then able to click Edit without touching any of the other controls.

Interestingly enough, the final XML from this item had only one `ph` set, with the others missing the parameter.

If you have a number of controls on the page adding `ph=""` might be faster, otherwise updating/viewing one of the controls might get Sitecore to update the Renderings XML.

Comment: Yep this did the trick. 1. Look for Controls inside the "Layout Details" area that have no "Placeholder"(name/key) value. 2. Add space, remove it, save. 3. Edit works! ----- In my case, I suspect a User removed the Placeholder key as a clunky way to stop it from displaying...

Comment: BUT the error did come back... UNTIL I edit the Placeholder under "Final Layout" section, and gave it a name (not just a blank/space). So indeed I think it does need some name/key value.

Comment: Not 100% I understand your last comment, but placeholders don't need a key/name to be set - you can set a default value on the control. However, this may be why it worked for me; I generally keep the default of "content" or set it to a more appropriate default.

Answer (score 0):

That just happened to me with Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 170407)

In my case it was actually the SHARED Renderings field that was messed up, still, the error was manifesting in Final Renderings (I guess it's when Sitecore tries to resolve layout differences against Shared).

Fixing Shared also fixes Final - we made it by restoring Shared values from default _Standard Values (Layout Restore on Shared Layouts).